# Why there is an "of" in the end?

Tags: grammar

I encountered a sentence which went like :

> "whatever was left was ransacked of."

And it confused me with the closing "of"

Comment: It does look odd, but you need to tell us where you found this sentence and what its context was.

Comment: That exact sentence has no search results.

Comment: Suspect it is regional slang. but more context or the source is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an odd phrasing, but the ‘of’ is necessary.

> Whatever was left was ransacked.

This is odd, and would mean that someone went through the remaining objects, stole things *from them*, and destroyed things *within them*.

> Whatever was left was ransacked of.

The remaining objects themselves were either damaged or stolen. The object that was actually ransacked, e.g., a home, was likely declared earlier, providing the context.